# My groff install doesn't have -k flag or preconv, what to do?

Tags: unix, encoding, macos-mojave

I am a newbie at using unix tools, but I really want to use groff. However, problem is I write in spanish, and some accents aren't rendered right on the final pdf. When I use `groff -mom -m pdfmark  doc | ps2pdf - doc.pdf`. I get this kind of mistakes with the accented characters such as `ó`

```
La letra escrita no implica gran comprensi³n.
```

This should read `La letra escrita no implica gran comprensión.`

I have read that groff doesn't support utf8 as the encoding of the input file, and that you have to preprocess it first. I tried to use the solution of this post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341783/whats-the-simplest-way-to-process-files-with-utf-8-characters-in-groff-on-macos, but 
I found out that my groff doesn't have neither the -k flag nor my system has  the ´preconv´ command.
Here is my `groff -h`, no `-k`, `-K` flags:

```
usage: groff [-abceghilpstvzCENRSUVXZ] [-Fdir] [-mname] [-Tdev] [-ffam]
   [-wname] [-Wname] [-Mdir] [-dcs] [-rcn] [-nnum] [-olist] [-Parg]
   [-Larg] [-Idir] [files...
```

I presume this is because I have a MacosX version of the tool, but that really doesn't convince me. Im using:

```
GNU groff version 1.19.2
```

If I `brew install` the latest groff, my terminal still uses the groff at `/usr/bin/groff`, not the one on the cellar.

So I'm stuck, any suggestion would help. 
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the groff mailing list and they confirmed this is only a version problem. MacOS comes shipped with very old versions of the software

Answer (score 0):

I was exactly at your point, and if I remember correctly, all that was left for me to do was actually open a *new* terminal, for it to use the newer version of `groff`.
Might that do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is indeed related to groff version, so once you have installed the new one, you can use that by typing

```
/usr/local/Cellar/groff/1.22.4/bin/groff -k ...
```

which is awful, but can be fixed by adding an alias in your bash profile

```
alias groff1="/usr/local/Cellar/groff/1.22.4/bin/groff"
```

so you only have to type

```
groff1 -k ...
```